# Why is System reading thousands of images from my hard drive constantly?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory

I have been getting poor performance while playing Minecraft recently, and I open up Resource monitor to see this:

[image: Crazy disk usage!]

Actually when I first opened it, I saw that pagefile.sys was at the top of the list, and I have 8 gigs of ram, 4 gigs of which is free when the computer is "idle", i.e. when I'm not playing my game. I'm wondering if that is caused by whatever System is doing with my pictures.

I've started considering disabling my page file, since MS says if a system has enough ram the pagefile most likely won't be necessary, but if this other thing keeps happening that's going to be a problem.

It just occurred to me that my C drive is 90% full at this point, could this be causing all of this?

Comment: use xperf/WPA to trace the callstack of the File/Disk IO: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-45-WPT-File--Registry-Analysis, http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-45-WPT-File--Registry-Analysis#c635146341508853528 Here you should see why the system tries to load the pictures.

Comment: I'd also try turning off indexing to see that's what it is.

Comment: oh, yeah, good point. I did actually turn that off a few weeks ago though.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the system is generating thumbnails for your pictures. If this is the case, you could try turning off thumbs.db caching and/or thumbnails.

http://www.sitepoint.com/switch-off-thumbs-db-in-windows/

Comment: I have no evidence that your answer is wrong, but I'm confused by the prospect of the system "generating" thumbnails when it only seems to be reading and not writing. However, if the OP were to sort the disk activity table by the "Write" column, we'd probably be able to tell more saliently what's going on.

Comment: Would it be adding thumbnails on images that were years old?
I'll try sorting it as the above commenter mentioned next time it starts doing it.

Comment: It hasn't started doing that again after it stopped sometime after I posted. I'll update you if it happens again. In the meantime I may try to get my new drive swapped in.